# My async/await function is not waiting in AWS Lambda. What am I missing?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a function in AWS Lambda to retrieve user details in Stripe. But the code after the function is executing first. What am I missing?

In my case, the function calls a Stripe function that returns a customer object.

I think the details of the Stripe function are not relevant for this specific question--the issue is the structure of my async/await:

```
module.exports.getUserName = async (event, context)=>{

  [code to get customerId from stripe]

  var customerName

  await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId, function(err, customer){
      if (err){}
      else{
       customerName = customer.name
     }
  })

  console.log('This should run after stripe.customers.retrieve')

}
```

Right now the console.log statement runs first. I've also tried wrapping the Stripe function in a separate async function, and also tried adding try/catch. But it's not working yet.

How can I be sure that the console log statement instead runs after `stripe.customers.retrieve` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**
I checked the [source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) for the npm stripe package. All the functions do return Promises, but if you additionally supply a callback, they're scheduled to be called on the next event loop (immediately after your console.log runs).

All you need to do is simply don't provide a callback if you'll be using the promise. Use `Promise.then()` instead:

```
await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId).then(customer => {
   customerName = customer.name
   resolve()
}).catch(_=>{})
```

---

Old answer (still works, but very redundant):

`await` is to be used with `Promise`s, it doesn't magically convert asynchronous code to synchronous. I can see from the old-fashioned `function(err, customer){` callback that your `stripe.customers.retrieve()` function does *not* return a Promise, so the `await` won't actually do anything.

You need to wrap it in a promise in order to use with `async/await`:

```
await new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
   stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId, function(err, customer) {
      if(!err) {
         customerName = customer.name
         resolve()
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, for me, your "old" answer--the full promise structure--works fully. The newer more concise answer does not quite work for me. The "customer" in "then(customer =>{" does not provide the full object; and the stripe.customers.retrieve function finishes its "function(err,customer)"--one of the params of function--after the console.log.

Comment: The difference could be related to the fact that your newer answer is based on the stripe npm package. My lambda function does not upload that directly--not sure if that makes a difference. In any event, the original answer works. So thanks again!