# Lambda function as SQS Event handler doesn't run a part of code and finishing successfully

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm using SQS and NodeJS lambda (as SQS Event handler) for creating/updating events in Google Calendar.
The code is similar to this

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis')

google.options({
  http2: true,
})
...
export const handler = async (event) => {
const schemaEvent = getDataFromEvent(event)
console.log('schemaEvent', schemaEvent)
const { data } = await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: CALENDAR_ID,
      requestBody: schemaEvent,
      sendUpdates: 'all',
    })
console.log('data', data)

}
...
```

When SQS receives many events (for ex.: 30), for some of events i can't see last `console.log('Data', data)` and code after that doesn't execute. But, if concurrency is set to 1 it works as expected.
What a reason of the problem can be?

Note:

- `BatchSize = 1` for handler
- SQS type is `FIFO`
- Dedupe is disabled

Logs ( `RequestId: e1c8a24b-8052-544e-8e44-f868b56273d5` wasn't processed till the end):

```
 
2021-12-02T22:56:15.211+02:00   START RequestId: 75dff3c9-26d5-5087-9110-a9ea13fba018 Version: $LATEST
2021-12-02T22:56:15.317+02:00   2021-12-02T20:56:15.299Z 75dff3c9-26d5-5087-9110-a9ea13fba018 INFO schemaEvent {... some data}
2021-12-02T22:56:16.176+02:00   2021-12-02T20:56:16.176Z 75dff3c9-26d5-5087-9110-a9ea13fba018 INFO data { ...some data }
2021-12-02T22:56:16.238+02:00   END RequestId: 75dff3c9-26d5-5087-9110-a9ea13fba018
2021-12-02T22:56:16.238+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 75dff3c9-26d5-5087-9110-a9ea13fba018 Duration: 1712.34 ms Billed Duration: 1713 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 164 MB

2021-12-02T22:56:16.512+02:00   START RequestId: e1c8a24b-8052-544e-8e44-f868b56273d5 Version: $LATEST
2021-12-02T22:56:16.717+02:00   2021-12-02T20:56:16.700Z e1c8a24b-8052-544e-8e44-f868b56273d5 INFO schemaEvent {...some data}
2021-12-02T22:56:18.225+02:00   END RequestId: e1c8a24b-8052-544e-8e44-f868b56273d5
2021-12-02T22:56:18.225+02:00   REPORT RequestId: e1c8a24b-8052-544e-8e44-f868b56273d5 Duration: 1710.32 ms Billed Duration: 1711 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 164 MB
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My async/await function is not waiting in AWS Lambda. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203672/my-async-await-function-is-not-waiting-in-aws-lambda-what-am-i-missing)

Comment: It doesn’t. `events.insert`is returning a Promise and code contains await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was in `googleapi`, solved by removing config options:

```js
google.options({
  http2: true,
})
```